# Como saber se um arquivo foi visualizado

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, arquivo, pdf

Estou fazendo um sistema em php onde o contador manda um arquivo para o cliente(utilizando banco de dados). 
Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como fazer para quando o cliente acessar este arquivo, seja mandado para o banco de dados a hora e a data em que foi aberto.

Consegui resolver.

Fiz o seguinte, assim que o usuário acessa o documento (através do modo *querystring*), eu faço um atualização num campo que tenho no banco de dados com o nome de "*data_visualizacao*" colocando a data atual através da função do sql "*CURRENT_TIMESTAMP* " e insiro *1* no campo *arquivo_lido*.
Assim na página onde estão listados os documentos salvos, eu faço uma condição: **se arquivo_lido for igual a 0**, então faço um destaque no título do arquivo para que o usuário saiba que aquele arquivo ainda não foi visualizado.

Comment: Você pode criar uma espécie de log de visualização do arquivo, poste mais detalhes, poste seu código, o que você já tentou?

Answer (score 3):

Controlar o exato momento em que o cliente abre um PDF eu acho impossível ou no mínimo tão invasivo que sequer deveria ser considerado.

O que você poderia fazer seria intermear o arquivo  e sua abertura/download.

Supondo que mantenha um controle de entradas e saídas de documentos completo num banco de dados incluindo o *path* do arquivo físico, com a velha técnica de *querystrings* (files.php?id=123) você pode mandar um e-mail para o cliente com um link contendo o ID daquele arquivo no seus controles o qual, quando acessado para download ou visualização no browser, você usaria para atualizar um campo que sirva de *flag* de controle.

No seu *dashboard*, onde você lista os documentos enviados e recebidos, você condiciona o valor dessa *flag*. Se zero (DEFAULT) o documento não foi lido/recebido e, comparando com a data você tem um feedback automático de que aquele cliente precisa de um contato pessoal, por telefone ou e-mail.

Se for 1 (um) ou outro valor positivo, o documento foi recebido e, também com base na data você tem como analisar o tempo médio para uma possível resposta.

No entanto, de novo, Isso não garante que o cliente leu o conteúdo, mas pelo menos você sabe que houve uma certa "interação" entre vocês.